# How can i access to a textbox in MainWindow from another form, without creating an instace of it in a WPF?

Tags: wpf, textbox

```
private void btnConfirmInMyForm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
//for example without creating like this
MainWindow mainWin = new MainWindow();
mainWin.txtBirthDate.Text = "anything";
this.close();
}
```

when i try the above, content of the txtBirthDate of new instance of MainWindow (mianWin) changes to "anything", but not in current MainWindow!
in other words as i click btnConfirmInMyForm in MyForm it opens a new MainWindow with the txtBirthDate textBox contains "anything", which i don't want!
i only want to set the txtBirthDate from MyForm, not to create a new MainWindow that contains this!

with best regards

Answer (score 0):

Is `btnConfirmInMyForm_Click` within your window? Then just try

```
this.txtBirthDate.Text = "anything";
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `MainWindow` is the Application's MainWindow, then you could try something like:

```
private void btnConfirmInMyForm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
  if (mainWindow != null)
    mainWindow.txtBirthDate.Text = "anything";
}
```

If it isn't you'd could pass your `MainWindow` object to the other `Window` to then use that object and assign the `Text`. You could also use something like a messaging pattern from MVVM to send messages across Views. There are quite a few options. What you pick is pretty much upto you.

Comment: thanks, i tried that, but i only receive the [tag:System.NullReferenceException] exception while my MainWindow is already open!
My MainWindow is the Application's MainWindow!

Comment: @user2693580 Works fine for me. I could upload the sample I tried if ya want and you could maybe check what's different.

Comment: @user2693580 [Download Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/levcjxn7qc16ygl/MainWindowSetter.rar) that should show it working. Window1.xaml.cs has the code for button click and it should set text in MainWindow's `TextBlock`

Comment: i found it, the exception was because of :


`<Application x:Class="DrugPerscription.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             `**StartupUri="LogIn.xaml"**`>
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>`
and i modified it to: **"StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"**

Comment: @user2693580 Yeh so as I stated, `MainWindow` was not set as your `Application.MainWindow`, LogIn.xaml was :P. Glad you solved it